# FileNotFoundException: Could not find file

Tags: asp.net

It's not an issue of my own but one I keep running into and I'd like it if someone could explain. I am applying at a university website and after uploading a document of mine, 2-4 days later I run into this error.

**Error**

> "Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find
> file (file name.jpg)"

**Stack Trace:**

```
    [FileNotFoundException: Could not find file (file name.jpg).]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +14584019
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +1430
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +208
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) +87
   System.Web.HttpResponse.WriteFile(String filename, Boolean readIntoMemory) +166
   System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.WriteFile(String filename) +30
   UGAdmission.Controllers.ApplicationController.Downloading(String path) +581
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1.<WrapVoidAction>b__0(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c() +112
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +241
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

A solution isn't required because I am sure this is an error from the university's side, but I would still like an explanation if possible.

Comment: yes, this is an error from the university's side. cause file remove or rename in server.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally when a file uploaded to any web application, file name suffix with current timestamp to generate unique name for file, so that another user can upload file with same name.

E.g. - name.jpg should save with name20200711040530.jpg

Moreover, Each websites has other logic to save , its depend on web application developmen team , how they wan to save files.

in your case, it seems file name is not mapped with actual file name or may be file rename or moved.